# Make children CSS attributes depend on parent element size (like media queries depend on browser width)

Tags: css

I have a form structure dependent on browser window width: to simplify question, assume it has three levels (begin from widest case):

1. Field label on the left, input field in the centre and field description on the right
2. Field label on the left, input field in the centre and field description below input field
3. Field label on the top, input field in the middle and field description on the bottom

It's done by something like this:

```
@media (max-width:1000px) { /* code for 1. */ }
@media (max-width:900px) { /* code for 2. */ }
@media (max-width:800px) { /* code for 3. */ }
```

What I'm asking for is to get the same functionality for **all** elements, so when I put a `form` into `div` which have `1000px` width, CSS will apply to that particular `form` same properties which are used to style 1st layout (`max-width:1000px`). When this `div` will shrink to `800px` the `form` should automatically restyle to the 3rd layout even when browse window still has width set to `1000px`.

Is it possible?

Comment: No, it's not possible in the way you envision. Media queries apply to the device, not HTML elements. But see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047605/using-iframe-to-apply-css-media-queries-to-block-elements, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251750/can-media-queries-resize-based-on-a-div-element-instead-of-the-screen.

Comment: Thank to you I found `css-element-queries` project. It does exactly what I want, except instead of using `@element` (what I expected), it uses `attributes`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to the second link in @torazaburo's comment under question post, I found the perfect solution:

https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries

Yet it's very young project it still **has some vulnerabilities (29 july 2013)** but also has a potential. It isn't based on `@element` queries but on `attributes`. Example:

```
.fooDiv[min-width="1000px"] .form { /* code for 1. */ }
.fooDiv[min-width="900px"] .form { /* code for 2. */ }
.fooDiv[min-width="800px"] .form { /* code for 3. */ }
```

Those attributes are set by listeners, so they work on each change of size of `.fooDiv`.

---

Another project (incompatible with SASS/SCSS),

https://github.com/Mr0grog/element-query

will work as follow:

```
.test-element:media(max-available-width: 400px) {
    background: purple;
}
```

> In the above CSS, `.test-element` will have a purple background if it is inside an element that is `400px` wide or smaller.

---

Yet another,

https://github.com/tysonmatanich/elementQuery
I use it in everyday projects.

---

Even more about this:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/06/25/media-queries-are-not-the-answer-element-query-polyfill/

Comment: I created a CSS container queries (aka element queries) prolyfill too: https://github.com/ausi/cq-prolyfill

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know if in terms of straight up css. You can combine jQuery to achieve this. An example of the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    box_size();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        box_size();
    });

    function box_size() {
        var window_width = $(window).width();

        $('.box').removeClass('break-one').removeClass('break-two').removeClass('break-three');

        if (window_width <= 1000 && window_width > 900) {
            $('.box').addClass('break-one');
        }
        else if (window_width <= 900 && window_width > 800) {
            $('.box').addClass('break-two');
        }
        else if (window_width <= 800) {
            $('.box').addClass('break-three');
        }
    }
});
```

The function is called twice. Once for when it loads to check the size and again when the browser resizes.

Css:

```
.box {
    color: black;
}

.box.break-one {
    color: red;
}

.box.break-two {
    color: blue;
}

.box.break-three {
    color: yellow;
}
```

Of course see it in action in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PWbvY/