# How can a bootstrap grid change column size based on the container?

Tags: html, grid, bootstrap-5

I currently have a reusable piece of HTML that consists of three bootstrap divs with a grid column size of 4 for each one, so they display side to side on a row. When there's enough space, they display just fine, but when they are on a smaller container (for example, if they are on a small section to the side), they are squashed because the space is too narrow and they don't look good. I want to solve this by making them stack on top of each other vertically if the space is too narrow and I can't solve this with media queries because they are based on the screen size, and I want to stack them vertically based on the container size.

Is there any way to accomplish this? Thank you for your time.

Here's an example code of what I have, what is the result when my containers are squashed on an small container and what I want to accomplish in the end.

```css
.container
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p>What I have</p>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: red;">
    Content 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: green;">
    Content 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: blue;">
    Content 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p>On an smaller container, the divs are too squashed</p>

<div class="container" style="width: 20%;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: red;">
    Content 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: green;">
    Content 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: blue;">
    Content 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p>What I want to get in the end</p>

<div class="container" style="width: 20%;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: red;">
    Content 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: green;">
    Content 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: blue;">
    Content 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why aren't you employing the [classes for smaller columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#grid-options)?

Comment: From what i read, you're looking to apply css rules based not on the screen-size but on the container size (so the parent element). I recommend you to check this post, it may be usefull : [make-children-css-attributes-depend-on-parent-element-size-like-media-queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914831/make-children-css-attributes-depend-on-parent-element-size-like-media-queries-d)

Comment: Classes for smaller columns doesn't work, I tried xs or sm but the problem is that I want them 4+4+4 columns when they have space but when the container space is too narrow I want to stack them like they do when the screen size is smaller. I also tried container queries but they don't seem to be widely used and I want to do this purely with bootstrap classes if possible. Overall I think there may be a simpler way to do this. But, if there's no better way of doing this, maybe I'll try that, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: https://caniuse.com/css-container-queries